# Adding items to a ListBox in a parallel way

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, task-parallel-library, backgroundworker

I'm writing a simple application (for testing purposes) that adds 10 M elements to a **ListBox**. I'm using a **BackgroundWorker** to do the work and a **ProgressBar** control to display the progress.

[image: My application]

Each element is a just a "*Hello World!*" string with and index that I'm adding during the process. My program takes ~ 7-8 seconds to fill the **ListBox**, and I thought if it's possible to speed up this, by using all the available cores on my PC (8).

To achieve that, I've tried to use the TPL library, more precise the **Parallel.For** loop, but the results are unpredictable or it doesn't work as I want it to.

Here's the code of my application:

```
    private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    private Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    private List<String> numbersList = new List<String>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        sw.Start();

        int max = 10000000;
        int oldProgress = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
        {
            numbersList.Add("Hello World! [" + i + "]");

            int progressPercentage = Convert.ToInt32((double)i / max * 100);

            // Only report progress when it changes
            if (progressPercentage != oldProgress)
            {
                worker.ReportProgress(progressPercentage);
                oldProgress = progressPercentage;
            }
        }
    }

    private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pb.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lstLoremIpsum.ItemsSource = numbersList;
        lblCompleted.Content = "OK";
        lblCompleted.Content += " (" + numbersList.Count + " elements added" + ")";
        lblElementiLista.Content += " (" +sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + ")";

        worker.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And the parallel implementation that I've tried to write (this goes in DoWork):

```
        Parallel.For(1, max, i =>
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                numbersList.Add("Hello World! [" + i + "]");
            }

            int progressPercentage = Convert.ToInt32((double)i / max * 100);

            // Only report progress when it changes
            if (progressPercentage != oldProgress)
            {
                worker.ReportProgress(progressPercentage);
                oldProgress = progressPercentage;
            }
        });
```

The results is that the application freezes, and takes about **15 seconds** to fill up my ListBox. (The elements are also unordered)

What can be done in this case and will parallelism speed up the "filling" process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lock statement in your thread basically reduces your parallel processing to sequential processing, but with the overhead of acquiring a lock (making it effectively slower).

Also there are a limited number of thread pool threads which can be used here so you won't get your full 10m concurrently adding.

I think a better way is to use a non UI thread to populate the list and then bind it afterwards - this will ensure the UI isn't frozen/unusable while the 10 million iteration loop is running:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(PopList);
}
```

Then you can call the UI thread when needed:

```
private void PopList()
{
    sw.Start();

    int max = 10000000;
    int oldProgress = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
    {
        numbersList.Add("Hello World! [" + i + "]");

        int progressPercentage = Convert.ToInt32((double)i / max * 100);

        // Only report progress when it changes
        if (progressPercentage != oldProgress)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { pb.Value = progressPercentage; }));                    
            oldProgress = progressPercentage;
        }
    }

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { lstLoremIpsum.ItemsSource = numbersList; }));
}
```

In an MVVM world you can just set the bound IEnumerable instead of the ItemsSource as shown in the above example.

Comment: Just 4.5 seconds, nice. How can I use all the cpu cores with your example?

Comment: If you start using Parallel.For again, you'll still need to implement a lock around the List object which will totally negate the parallel processing and make it slower.  This isn't really a CPU bound task - and List.Add is very, very quick, so there isn't really a CPU load to spread here.

Comment: So there's no way to further speed up this? If it's not a really CPU related task, where should I look at then? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to speed this up without a cost elsewhere. You could try splitting the job up, so you have 10 parallel threads populating 1-1000000, 1000001-2000000 etc.  But at the end you'll still need to concatenate the lists and that will take time.

Comment: I'll look into that approach, I thought about that too. Thanks again. Since I just love Tasks, I'm marking your answer as the best one!

Answer (score 0):

You are locking the list on each add, and all the process load is just that, adding an element to the list, so instead of speeding up things you are slowing them because there are really no parallel work.

If your list of items is of a known size (as it seems), instead of a list create an array with the appropiated size and then in the parallel for loop set the appropiated item to it's value, in this way no locking is performed and it should be faster.

Also, in your code you don't show when the list view is populated, just the list, so I suppose you are using this list as datasource, before setting it do a listView.BeginUpdate() and after setting it listView.EndUpdate(), it may speed up things a bit,m the listview is a bit slow when adding elements.

Comment: Actually, if the NumbersList property is being used as an ItemsSource of the ListView, I guess it would be faster to simply populate a different array with the items and then set the NumbersList property to `New List<String>(NumbersArray)`, instead of Adding each item directly to the ItemsSource one by one.

Comment: No, you got it wrong, first populate the array ant once populated then set the array as the itemssource, why add it to a list if you can already use the array?

Comment: Well, there are a variety of reasons you could prefer a List over an Array as an ItemsSource... But anyway, was just referring to the fact that setting the collection as ItemsSource and THEN adding the items one by one was anything but optimal :P Which is what he seems to be doing now

Comment: I doubt it, a List<> is not an observable collection, if you just add items to it the ListView will not be informed of those changes, so no, he is not doing that.

Comment: Now that you mention it, he's doesn't seem to be using INotifyPropertyChanged either. Wonder how the items get updated, then.

Comment: As i said, he is setting it to the item's property once the list has been filled.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Parallel.For, then you don't need a BackgroundWorker. And the Worker doesn't work anymore as expected anyway, since you're trying to access it from another thread.

Remove the BackgroundWorker and do the Parallel.For directly, using Interlocked methods to update the progress bar:

```
private int ProgressPercentage { get; set; }

private void DoWork()
{
    Parallel.For(1, max, i =>
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            numbersList.Add("Hello World! [" + i + "]");
        }

        int progressPercentage = Convert.ToInt32((double)i / max * 100);

        // Only report progress when it changes
        if (progressPercentage != oldProgress)
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ProgressPercentage, progressPercentage);
            ShowProgress();
        }
    });
}

private void ShowProgress()
{
    pb.Value = ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Comment: I've changed it into Interlocked.Exchange(ref ProgressPercentage, progressPercentage) but VS is getting angry "A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter";

Comment: Mmmmh... Can't try this right now, but what if you change ProgressPercentage to be a regular field instead of a property? `private int progressPercentage;`

Comment: If I change it to be a field, the error disappears, but it throws another one, saying it can't access this object on another thread, on ShowProgress() function. I suppose this is a typical cross-thread exception.